# Unexpected values in hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to create a maze generator and I'm having some trouble with my code. At the beginning of my script, I create a multidimensional array (`@maze`) with X number of columns and Y number of rows. There is a loop which iterates through the array and sets all of the elements to an initial value of 1. The `get_neighbors` sub routine is suppose to create a hash with `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` keys. It then sets the values for these keys based on the `x` and `y` coords which get passed in. For the `top` key, I set it's value to the element directly above which should be `[ $y - 1 ][ $x ]`. I was assuming that if for example, the coords, `0, 0` were passed in, `top` would be set to undef since that's not a valid element / position, but it's not.. It's being set to 1. Not sure why.. Was hoping someone could spot and explain why that's happening. Here's the entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Switch;
use Data::Dumper;

# Rows is set equal to the first arg passed in
# unless it hasn't been. If it hasn't been, the
# value defaults to 60. This also applies to the
# columns.
my $rows  = (defined($ARGV[ 0 ]) ? $ARGV[ 0 ] : 60);
my $cols  = (defined($ARGV[ 1 ]) ? $ARGV[ 1 ] : 60);
my $cells = $rows * $cols;

my @maze;

# "Pre-allocate" each "Cell" for the maze.
for(my $y = 0; $y < $rows; ++$y) {
    for(my $x = 0; $x < $cols; ++$x) { $maze[ $y ][ $x ] = 1; }
} 

# Run 
main();

#--------------------------
# Main ~
#--------------------------
sub main {
    print Dumper(get_neighbors(0, 0));

    generate();
    print_maze();   

    return;
}

#--------------------------
# Generate the maze w/ BFS
#--------------------------
sub generate {

    return;
}

#--------------------------
# Print maze to console
#--------------------------
sub print_maze {
    for(my $y = 0; $y < $rows; ++$y) {
        for(my $x = 0; $x < $cols; ++$x) {
            print $maze[ $y ][ $x ] . " ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}

#--------------------------
# Returns the values of 
# neighboring cells 
#--------------------------
sub get_neighbors {
    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;

    my %neighbors;

    $neighbors{'top'}    = defined($maze[ $y - 1 ][ $x ]) ? $maze[ $y - 1 ][ $x ] : undef; 
    $neighbors{'bottom'} = defined($maze[ $y + 1 ][ $x ]) ? $maze[ $y + 1 ][ $x ] : undef;
    $neighbors{'left'}   = defined($maze[ $y ][ $x - 1 ]) ? $maze[ $y ][ $x - 1 ] : undef;
    $neighbors{'right'}  = defined($maze[ $y ][ $x + 1 ]) ? $maze[ $y ][ $x + 1 ] : undef;

    return %neighbors;
}
```

The out when I run this script is:

```
# perl mazegen.pl 10 10
$VAR1 = 'left';
$VAR2 = 1;
$VAR3 = 'right';
$VAR4 = 1;
$VAR5 = 'top';
$VAR6 = 1;
$VAR7 = 'bottom';
$VAR8 = 1;
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Note that `$neighbors{'top'}    = defined($maze[ $y - 1 ][ $x ]) ? $maze[ $y - 1 ][ $x ] : undef` is *identical* to `$neighbors{'top'} = $maze[ $y-1][$x]`. Also, you can use the defined-or for `my $rows  = (defined($ARGV[ 0 ]) ? $ARGV[ 0 ] : 60)` to write `my $rows = $ARGV[ 0 ] // 60`. It is also nicer to avoid the C-style `for` loop and iterate over a range instead, so `for(my $y = 0; $y < $rows; ++$y) { ... }` becomes `for my $y ( 0 .. $rows-1 ) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl, a negative subscript on an array counts from the end of the array.

For example:

```
my @foo = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

say $foo[-2];
```

would display `d`.

This should illustrate what's happening:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @maze = ( [ 'a' .. 'e' ],
             [ 'f' .. 'j' ],
             [ 'k' .. 'o' ],
             [ 'p' .. 't' ],
             [ 'u' .. 'y' ], );

for my $row (@maze) {
    say "@$row";
}

my %neighbors;
my ($x, $y) = (0, 0);

# The // defined-or was added in Perl 5.10.  These are equivalent:
# $foo = defined($bar) ? $bar : 'toast';
# $foo = $bar // 'toast';

$neighbors{'top'}    = $maze[ $y - 1 ][ $x ] // '-'; 
$neighbors{'bottom'} = $maze[ $y + 1 ][ $x ] // '-';
$neighbors{'left'}   = $maze[ $y ][ $x - 1 ] // '-';
$neighbors{'right'}  = $maze[ $y ][ $x + 1 ] // '-';

say "  $neighbors{top}";
say "$neighbors{left} $maze[$y][$x] $neighbors{right}";
say "  $neighbors{bottom}";
```

Output:

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p q r s t
u v w x y
  u
e a b
  f
```

Comment: Also, not an answer, just a suggestion: Don't use [`Switch`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch#NAME).  It'll cause nasty headaches down the road.

Comment: Ah, yes I think I remember reading about that at one point. I'll change my code to check if the coords are within boundaries and set undef if not. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$neighbors{ top    } = $y > 0              ? $maze[ $y - 1 ][ $x ] : undef;
$neighbors{ bottom } = $y < $#maze         ? $maze[ $y + 1 ][ $x ] : undef;
$neighbors{ left   } = $x > 0              ? $maze[ $y ][ $x - 1 ] : undef;
$neighbors{ right  } = $x < $#{ $maze[0] } ? $maze[ $y ][ $x + 1 ] : undef;
```